# Carrierwave uploader: How to add a link to remove an uploaded file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have one uploader that is used in the profile of three different types of users to upload their avatar or logo. I'm using carrierwave and fog here, and a S3 bucket in production. This works. Now I would like to include a link to remove the avatar/logo if that user wants to. So it should't delete the entire record of the user, just that one variable (avatar/logo). I'm using the code below.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. **What am I doing wrong here?** The error: `Couldn't find User without an ID` referring to the controller line `User.friendly.find(params[:id]).avatar.destroy`. (`friendly` comes from the friendly_id gem.)

Users controller:

```
  def destroy_avatar
    User.friendly.find(params[:id]).avatar.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Avatar deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end
```

Routes:

```
  delete 'avatar'           =>  'users#destroy_avatar'
```

Link in view:

```
  <% if @users.avatar? %>
    <%= link_to "Remove avatar", avatar_path(@user), method: :delete %>
  <% end %>
```

Despite the error message `@user` does have a value, because it is used all over the view page for other variables that function properly.

---

The server log says about the request:

```
Started DELETE "/avatar.fakename1"
Processing by UsersController#destroy_avatar as 
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"ZYVI***AZy34jYzQ=="}
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User without an ID):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:68:in `destroy_avatar'
```

And it has the following request parameters:

```
{"_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>"ZYVIEy1***DYGICxgi4jYzQ==",
 "format"=>"fakename1"}
```

Comment: What does the request look like in the Rails log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a rails path helper with a parameter, the route needs to reflect that.

Basically you need to do `delete 'avatar/:id' => 'users#destroy_avatar', as: avatar` in your routes so that you can pass a param to the path helper.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the routes file and restarted the server. But on loading the page it now produces the error: `undefined method `avatar_path' `. referring to the `link_to` line in the view page.

Comment: Right, I believe the path will be called `destroy_avatar_path`, but i'm not sure. Try going to your terminal and typing `rake routes` and you can see what the path names are. The values on the far left are what the route helper names are. For example, you might see `destroy_avatar DELETE /avatar/:id users#destroy_avatar` so your path helper would be `destroy_avatar_path`

Comment: Sorry, my mistakes seem to add up. It didn't have any name on the left. But if I add `, as: 'avatar'` to the routes file, the page renders but clicking the delete link now produces the error: `undefined method 'destroy' `, referring to `.destroy` in the controller method.

Comment: Haha no worries, yeah I forgot plain routes won't give you helpers unless you add that "as" param. Looks like your issue now is that the user does not have an avatar. Try putting in a breakpoint and see what `User.friendly.find(params[:id]).avatar` gives you.

Comment: The user does have an avatar because the avatar is shown on that same page and the delete link is only shown if an avatar exists (`if @user.avatar?`). The regular destroy method to destroy the entire record in that same controller is exactly the same but without the `.avatar`. And that method does work. Is the `.avatar` in the controller method perhaps not possible this way?  I also tried in the controller: `    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])` `@user.avatar.destroy` but that made no difference.

Comment: Ohhh I see the issue. `destroy` is a method for active record objects. Avatar must just be an attribute on user. What you want is most likely `User.friendly.find(params[:id]).update_attribute(:avatar, nil)`

Comment: Using `@user.update_attribute(:avatar, nil)` I get the error `Missing template users/destroy_avatar, application/destroy_avatar with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. etc....`  I also tried `@user.update_attributes(avatar: nil)` but that gave the same error. I removed the lines `flash[:success] = "Avatar deleted"` and `redirect_to users_url` from the controller method because otherwise it would render the flash message and index (did not show the error message) but it hadn't updated the avatar.

Comment: Interesting. Well apparently carrier wave provides the method `remove_avatar!` which will remove the attached avatar. From the github page it says
`@user.remove_avatar!` then `@user.save`.

Also, if you removed the redirect_to then it will automatically try to render a template based on the controller action. You have to either A. create the template or B. force it to render a different template or redirect somewhere else.